# mssql openquery update/add/delete row linked mysql

Tags: mysql, sql-server

I have two databases. The first is the mssql database, the second is mysql. I need to periodically check the changes in the first and send them to the second. The easiest way is to delete the data in the second one and transfer everything again, but it takes too long

```
delete FROM openquery(trade, 'select * from towary') where id < 9999
INSERT INTO openquery(trade, 'select id,symbol,nazwa,cena,stan from towary')
SELECT [tw_Id] as id
      ,[tw_Symbol] as symbol
      ,[tw_Nazwa] as nazwa
      ,([tc_CenaNetto2]*1.1) as cena
      ,[st_Stan] as stan
  FROM [veen].[dbo].[vwTowar]
  where st_Stan > 0
```

I can ask for any suggestions

Comment: What's taking so long ? the insert ? or the delete? how many rows are you  triying to insert / delete ?

Comment: It can only be one of a few things that cause these types of issues. Data quantity, transfer rate, or indexes.  Indexes and data quantity basically go hand in hand.

Also realize on the insert select you are combining reads and writes.  Anything also going on actively in these databases will impact the performance.

Comment: The best solution would be to compare the mssql database to the myslq database and make changes to the mysql database. For two mssql databases, I don't see much of a problem, but the combination of mssql and mysql is problematic for me. 
There are about 2,000 records in mssql at the moment, but it will keep growing. id is a maximum of 10 characters, symbol 20, nazwa 50, cena 10, ilosc 10. Synchronization takes up to 10 minutes and it is not the best solution to delete all records and add them again.